# Many-to-many relation in yii2 activedataprovider

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, many-to-many, cactivedataprovider

I have many-to-many relation with three tables: `Category`, `Product`, `ProductCategory`.
Relation in `Category`:

```
public function getProductCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductCategory::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Relation in `Product`:

```
    public function getProductCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductCategory::ClassName(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And in `ProductCategory`

```
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), ['id' => 'product_id']);
}

public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

In my Category Controller I used this code to show the products I need according to their category (one-to-many):

```
    $cats = Category::findOne(['slug1'=>$slug1]);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([

        'query' => $query = Product::find()->where(['category_id' => $cats->id]),
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>['id' => SORT_ASC],
        ),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 9,
        ],
    ]);
```

So the question is how to make my ActiveDataProvider to get in query the many-to-many relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two more relations like this

In category:

```
public function getProducts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['id' =>   'product_id'])->via("productCategories");
}
```

And in product:

```
public function getCategories()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Category::ClassName(), ['id' =>   'category_id'])->via("productCategories");
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
$cats = Category::findOne(['slug1'=>$slug1]);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([

    'query' => $query = $cats->getProducts(),
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>['id' => SORT_ASC],
    ),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 9,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! But the question was how to pass this relation to the $query to show relative Products in my view.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, just write ` 'query' => $cats->getProducts()`

Comment: Just add $query = Product::find()->where(['category_id' => $cats->id])->joinWith(['Category']);

Comment: so strange, now I have an error:
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
app\models\Category has no relation named "productsCategories".
(it's the answer to Golub)

Comment: as to  Sfili_81 comment,
it first told me it's case sensitive< so I just replaced 'Category' with 'category'.
Now it renders my page but shows no products in this categories :(

Comment: phew! I have found the error. In Golub's code there's via("productsCategories") 
while it should be 
via("productCategories")
thank you very much!

Comment: @andrew sorry for typo, I'm glad I was able to help.