# How make a many-to-many rest API in yii2

Tags: php, rest, yii2, many-to-many

I'm trying to get a many-to-may relationship to work, but I can't get it to work.

I have a database with 3 tables: `users`, `favorites` & `videos`. The favorites table contains 2 `foreign keys` that point to the users table and the videos table.

Currently I have the following:

User Model:

```
public function getVideos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Video::class, ['id' => 'video_id'])->viaTable(UserFavorites::tableName(), ['favorite_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Video Model:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, ['id' => 'user_id'])->via(UserFavorites::tableName());
}
```

VideoController: (ActiveController)

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider'];
    return $actions;
}

public function prepareDataProvider()
{
    $user = User::findOne('1=1');
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
       'query' => $user->getVideos()
    ]);
}
```

Following what they did in:
[Many-to-many relation in yii2 activedataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321871/many-to-many-relation-in-yii2-activedataprovider)
but that did not work. I also tried with `extraFields` and `expand` with no luck.

How do I make it so the result will look sorta like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "video name",
    "likes": 69,
    "user": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    }]
},
...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need to update the code in a few places.

**The `REST` active controller**.

It looks like you are trying to get **one** video with the user's that liked it, you should be using the view action, not the index action, that should be used to get a list of videos, you can use the base `view` action, no need to override it, it will work like you need it.

In the controller, should be enough with setting the model.

```php
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class VideoController extends ActiveController
{    
    public $modelClass = Video::class;
}
```

Consider setting `$_verbs` and `actionOptions` if you need them to not be the default.

**The model**.

You should use `extraFields` to expose the method as a field.

```php
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Video extends ActiveRecord
{
    // Other methods here...

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, ['id' => 'user_id'])
            ->viaTable(UserFavorites::tableName(), [
                'video_id' => 'id'
            ]);
    }

    public function extraFields()
    {
        return [
            'users'
        ];
    }
}
```

If you want to use the same name for the API call as the function, i.e. the API call uses `expand=users` and the method is called `getUsers()` you can use the `users` shortcut on `expandFields`, if the names are different, you can use the expanded format, i.e. `'likes' => 'users'`

Then, querying your API with:

`https://apiv1.example.com/videos/45?expand=users`

Should give you the expected results like in your post

```
[{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "video name",
    "likes": 69,
    "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    }]
},
...
]
```

Notice that the array of users will be called 'users' and not 'user' if you configured the same way, you can change that using the expanded notation inside `extraFields`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how the dots are connected; I changed the method name to `getUsers` and the extra field name to `users`. I'm now getting a "has no relation named ...' error.

Comment: I just noticed you are using `via` but giving it a table name instead of a relation name. Check the documentation for that on the [Yii docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerelationtrait#via()-detail) One way to fix it would be to use `viaTable` I will update the answer.